# Transpose columns to rows using SQL query, maybe using pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

Input :

```
Empl ID Name January-16 February-16 March-16    Activity 
----------------------------------------------------------
1234    Test1   30         10         1         Running 
1234    Test1   0           0         8         Sleeping
4567    Test2   20         20         2         Reading 
4567    Test2   0          30         20        Reading 
2345    Test3   10         10         3         Sleeping
2345    Test3   0           0         9         Running
```

into :

```
Empl ID Name    Date        Costs   Activity 
--------------------------------------------------
1234    Test1   January-16   30     Running 
1234    Test1   February-16  10     Running 
1234    Test1   March-16     1      Running 
1234    Test1   March-16     8      Sleeping
```

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc..?

Comment: Yep unpivot but the way of doing it is different if you are using mysql than sql-server, than oracle....etc so which rdbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using sql server

Comment: What have you tried? Microsoft provides documentation for the `UNPIVOT` operation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'm not that familiar with pivot and unpivot syntax and tried using "case", "Union all". Seems like that is not an option.

Comment: UNPIVOT - this is what you need to use.

Comment: UNPIVOT will work, union all would work too if you build it right because that is what UNPIVOT does in the background.

Comment: Thank you all. Got it right using both union all and unpivot.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    #Table
    UNPIVOT (
       Costs FOR C IN ([January-16], [February-16], [March-16])
    ) up
WHERE
    Costs <> 0
```